# Call function automatically without an explicit call in every implementation of another function in subclasses

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass, implicit

I've got something similar to the code below. I would like to add a bit of code to the end of each `bar` function e.g., `foo`.  I think I might need to use `type` classes and `implicit` or perhaps `abstract override`. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
trait A {
  def foo = { //do something }
}


case class B() extends A {
  def bar = {
    // do other stuff
    // automatically call foo
  }
}

case class C() extends A {
  def bar = {
    // do different stuff
    // automatically call foo
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make **every** method in **every** derived class call `foo` automatically, or is it just some (pre-determined) set of methods?

Comment: Well, `abstract override` methods sort of can call things automatically. You may want to look into those.

Comment: Yes indeed I would like a single method `bar` every derived class to call `foo` automatically as the last thing is does I will revise the question to clarify this immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it call automatically. How should the compiler know what to call? Magic?

You can impl. a default `bar` and call `super.bar`

```
def bar = foo
....
def bar = {
//do stuff
super.bar
}
```

but unless `bar` calls multiple methods, this is useless.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like `after` in aspect-oriented programming. The easiest way to do this in any OO language is to follow the rule that public methods are always final. This separates the interface between the base and derived classes from the interface between the base class and its callers. That is:

```
trait A {
    private def foo = { }
    protected def on_bar = { }
    final def bar = { on_bar; foo; }
};

case class B() extends A {
    def on_bar = { do_other_stuff; }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I have clarified the problem a bit as I think I had left it somewhat unclear. I will mark this accepted if I don't get further answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what's you're up to, but it sounds similar to the [stackable trait pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html). Have a look and tell if it's something that you want, in that case I can provide more info on that, even though that article is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the question and I hope that clarifies it. Does it still sound like the stackable trait pattern is the way to go?